# Unable to update object in angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Right now, I am able to create objects and save them to a rails database through a json api.  It is a simple todo list app that when I add an object, it goes into the todo list above the input fields.  I am also able to query all the objects on the index view and list all of my todo objects.

When I click on a checkbox next to each todo item, it is supposed to change it's :done attribute to true, so that I do not show it anymore after they click a "Clear" button which is the `clearCompleted` function.

Here is my js code

```
angular.module("Todo", ["ngResource"])

function TodoController($scope, $filter, $resource) {
  Todo = $resource("/todos.json", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}})
    $scope.todos = Todo.query()

  $scope.getTotalTodos = function () {
      return $scope.todos.length;
  };

  $scope.clearCompleted = function () {
    Todo.save({done:true})
    $scope.todos = $filter("filter")($scope.todos, {done:false});
};

  $scope.addTodo = function () {
    entry = Todo.save({title:$scope.newTodo.title, importance:$scope.newTodo.importance, description:$scope.newTodo.description, done:false})
    $scope.todos.push(entry);
    $scope.newTodo.title = '';
    $scope.newTodo.importance = '';
    $scope.newTodo.description = '';
  };

}
```

What is happening is that rather than updating that object in the database, it is creating a brand new todo item and just giving it the attribute of `:done => true`.   It makes sense because in that `clearCompleted` function it looks like we are creating an object not updating an existing one.

How do I update the record in the database then?

Comment: where do you put the id in param?

Comment: are you referring to the resource method? Have it there because I was following a railscast.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Todo.save({})` to update a  todo. As you said it create a  new object.

Write code as follows.

```
 Todo = $resource("/todos.json", {id: "@id"}, {'save': {method: 'PUT'}})
 $scope.todos = Todo.query();
    var todo =  todos[0];//A todo that should be updated
    todo.done = true;
    todo.$save();
```

Mabe you need a parameter for todo key in your save url.

**[using $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)**

Comment: Are we really getting the first todo or should we be getting the todo's that were updated?  When we click the check box we are trying to change an attribute.

Comment: It looks like the save creates another object.  How would I change this to update the attributes.

Comment: Is your service a RESTfull service?

Comment: yes it is.  The issue I am seeing now is that even when I do the update method the right parameters are being passed in but it is a POST request and not a PUT request in the terminal.

Comment: Try {'save': {method: 'PUT'} // note the single quotation and call it as i mentioned in my post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44647/discussion-between-alborz-and-user2184718)